# ModelRenderable with multiple submeshes only showing one submesh

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I need to combine several cubes in ARCore to become one ModelRenderable. I have code that is taking the vertices and submeshes from each cube and creating one ModelRenderable, however, only the last cube added is rendered.

I have only the last cube added showing, as previously said. The one strange thing I can see is that there are vertices that have the same positions, so I'm not sure if that's correct or not.

Here's my code taking each cube and adding the submeshes and vertices.

```
List<RenderableDefinition.Submesh> submeshes = new ArrayList<>();
List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();

for (SubCube cube : cubes) {
    submeshes.add(cube.getSubmesh());
    vertices.addAll(cube.getVertices());
}

RenderableDefinition renderableDefinition = RenderableDefinition.builder().setVertices(vertices).setSubmeshes(submeshes).build();
CompletableFuture future = ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(renderableDefinition).build();

ModelRenderable result = (ModelRenderable) future.get();
```

Here's my code for creating a cube. It's basically identical to ShapeFactory.makeCube.

```
    public SubCube makeCube(Vector3 size, Vector3 center, Material material) {
        AndroidPreconditions.checkMinAndroidApiLevel();
        Vector3 extents = size.scaled(0.5F);
        Vector3 p0 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(-extents.x, -extents.y, extents.z));
        Vector3 p1 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(extents.x, -extents.y, extents.z));
        Vector3 p2 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(extents.x, -extents.y, -extents.z));
        Vector3 p3 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(-extents.x, -extents.y, -extents.z));
        Vector3 p4 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(-extents.x, extents.y, extents.z));
        Vector3 p5 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(extents.x, extents.y, extents.z));
        Vector3 p6 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(extents.x, extents.y, -extents.z));
        Vector3 p7 = Vector3.add(center, new Vector3(-extents.x, extents.y, -extents.z));
        Vector3 up = Vector3.up();
        Vector3 down = Vector3.down();
        Vector3 front = Vector3.forward();
        Vector3 back = Vector3.back();
        Vector3 left = Vector3.left();
        Vector3 right = Vector3.right();
        Vertex.UvCoordinate uv00 = new Vertex.UvCoordinate(0.0F, 0.0F);
        Vertex.UvCoordinate uv10 = new Vertex.UvCoordinate(1.0F, 0.0F);
        Vertex.UvCoordinate uv01 = new Vertex.UvCoordinate(0.0F, 1.0F);
        Vertex.UvCoordinate uv11 = new Vertex.UvCoordinate(1.0F, 1.0F);
        List<Vertex> vertices = Arrays.asList(
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p0).setNormal(down).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p1).setNormal(down).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p2).setNormal(down).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p3).setNormal(down).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p7).setNormal(left).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p4).setNormal(left).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p0).setNormal(left).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p3).setNormal(left).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p4).setNormal(front).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p5).setNormal(front).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p1).setNormal(front).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p0).setNormal(front).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p6).setNormal(back).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p7).setNormal(back).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p3).setNormal(back).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p2).setNormal(back).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p5).setNormal(right).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p6).setNormal(right).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p2).setNormal(right).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p1).setNormal(right).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p7).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uv01).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p6).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uv11).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p5).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uv10).build(),
                Vertex.builder().setPosition(p4).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uv00).build());

        ArrayList<Integer> triangleIndices = new ArrayList(36);

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            triangleIndices.add(3 + 4 * i);
            triangleIndices.add(1 + 4 * i);
            triangleIndices.add(0 + 4 * i);
            triangleIndices.add(3 + 4 * i);
            triangleIndices.add(2 + 4 * i);
            triangleIndices.add(1 + 4 * i);
        }

        RenderableDefinition.Submesh submesh = RenderableDefinition.Submesh.builder().setTriangleIndices(triangleIndices).setMaterial(material).build();
        return new SubCube(submesh, vertices);
    }
```

I'm not getting error messages or anything. I know the passed-in positions to makeCube are different, so that's not the issue. Expected behavior is that I'm able to render more than one cube in one ModelRenderable.

Comment: I have successfully defeated the StackOverflow boss battle

Answer (score 2):

As you merge all the vertices in a final array (named `vertices`), the triangle indices should be offset in each sub cube.

- For the first cube, index values go from 0 to 23 (as you have 24 vertices per cube)
- For the second cube, index values go from 24 to 47
- For the i<sup>th</sup> cube, index values go from (i-1)*24 to i*24-1

Otherwise you can achieve the same result by creating only one cube geometry and a node hierarchy with each sub node using that renderable but a different position.